# PL SQL loop through list of ids

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have a list of names.

john, sam, peter, jack

I want to query the same sql with each of above as the filter. Each query will give me a unique employee id, which I want to use to delete some other records.

```
select emp_id from employee where emp_name like '%john%';
```

Let's say for the first query, I get the id as 1001. So the delete queries would be like following.

```
delete from account_details where emp_id = 1001;
delete from hr_details where emp_id = 1001;
delete from pay_role_details where emp_id = 1001;
```

I have to repeat this for a list of employees. Pseudocode would be like following.

```
var emp_list = ['john', 'jack', 'kate', 'peter', 'sam',...]

for each :employee_name in emp_list
    select emp_id as :var_emp_id from employee where emp_name like '%:employee_name%'; 

    delete from account_details where emp_id = :var_emp_id;
    delete from hr_details where emp_id = :var_emp_id;
    delete from pay_role_details where emp_id = :var_emp_id;
end loop
```

I want a PL-SQL query to do this. Please help. Thanks.

What I tried is something like the following.

```
set serveroutput on;
begin
loop x in ('john','jack', 'kate') loop as :name
  select emp_id as var_emp_id from employee where emp_name like '%:name%';
  // delete queries  
end loop;
end;
```

P.S. Although accoring to the question, like query may result in multiple records, in actual scenario, it is guaranteed to be only one record. Why I use like is that in actual scenario, it is a list of reference numbers instead of names. The reference number has some other pre texts and post texts and my comma seperated list has only the numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the following will help:

```
BEGIN
  FOR aName IN (SELECT 'john'  AS EMP_NAME FROM DUAL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'sam'   AS EMP_NAME FROM DUAL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'peter' AS EMP_NAME FROM DUAL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'jack'  AS EMP_NAME FROM DUAL)
  LOOP
    FOR emp IN (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_NAME LIKE '%' || aName.EMP_NAME || '%')
    LOOP
      DELETE FROM ACCOUNT_DETAILS a WHERE a.EMP_ID = emp.EMP_ID;
      DELETE FROM HR_DETAILS h WHERE h.EMP_ID = emp.EMP_ID;
      DELETE FROM PAY_ROLE_DETAILS p WHERE p.EMP_ID = emp.EMP_ID;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Deleted data for employee with EMP_ID=' || emp.EMP_ID);
    END LOOP;  -- emp
  END LOOP; -- aName
END;
```

Study this until you understand how and why it works.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a cursor to do so? Try to skip cursor if possible to avoid poor performance/memory usage on huge data.

```
delete from account_details inner join employee on account_details.emp_id = employee.emp_id where WHERE CONTAINS(employee.emp_name, '"John" OR "Sam" OR "Max"', 1) >0;

delete from hr_details inner join employee on hr_details.emp_id = employee.emp_id where WHERE CONTAINS(employee.emp_name, '"John" OR "Sam" OR "Max"', 1) >0;

delete from pay_role_details inner join employee on pay_role_details.emp_id = employee.emp_id where WHERE CONTAINS(employee.emp_name, '"John" OR "Sam" OR "Max"', 1) >0;
```

Comment: Sure, you don't need a cursor per se, however, he specifically asked for a PL/SQL procedure and imho a cursor fits better in that case. But as always, everything has its advantages & disadvantages.

Comment: agree if his criteria is more complex that need more logic to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Use a PL/SQL cursor to select all the IDs you want to delete and then just loop it and issue the DELETE statements with every pass.

In-depth info on cursors can be found here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html

For dynamic SQL see here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS627

Code example:

```
    PROCEDURE delete_stuff
    IS

    id AS NUMBER;

    CURSOR your_cursor IS
    SELECT emp_id FROM employee WHERE CONTAINS(employee.emp_name, '"John" OR "Sam" OR "Max"', 1) > 0;

    OPEN your_cursor;
        LOOP
        FETCH your_cursor INTO id;
        EXIT WHEN your_cursor%NOTFOUND;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM account_details WHERE emp_id = :id' USING id;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM hr_details WHERE emp_id = :id' USING id;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM pay_role_details WHERE emp_id = :id' USING id;

    CLOSE your_cursor;
    END LOOP;

    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;


END delete_stuff;
```

Comment: Personal preference. Imho it is way more versatile in case you need to adjust things or suddenly need to fulfill more complex demands.